# Reference current file with go:generate

Tags: go

is there any way for `go:generate` to reference the current file?

For example, I'd like to do something similar to

`//go:generate sometool $FILE`

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can refer current file as follows:

```
//go:generate sometool $GOFILE
```

`$GOFILE` get expanded to be name of the file processed by go generate.